# Refreshing "contentComponent" in Drawer Navigator (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, components, navigation-drawer

I am trying to display user name and user picture in the side bar menu of the drawer navigator. Therefore, I am using a custom content component.

I am looking for a possibility to refresh the content component if some of the values (for example users picture) is changing. I saw some solutions with react-redux, but I am not using react-redux and I am looking for a solution without the need of react-redux. I couldn´t find any useful solution in web, so I hope that someone could give me a example of refreshing content component in a easy way, without the need of react-redux.